# Enter E-GPV gamepad not recognising all button presses

Tags: windows-7, drivers, gaming, game-controller

I am using Enter E-GPV gamepad on Windows 7.

I opted to buy this as I did not have any previous experience of using gamepads and this had the highest available user rating and the cheapest best option available. I am having a problem while playing the game. I cannot perform any skill moves in FIFA 13 and I am not able to use the RS and LS of the gamepad.

I did some research and found that my computer is not recognising the gamepad LS and RS and it is thus producing the basic functions only. Please help me to sort out the problem.

Comment: This is not really the place to ask questions about video-games and game-controllers.  Problems as you describe should be brought to the manufacturer of either the game, or the hardware you wish to use.  This is much too specific to actually be useful to anyone besides yourself.

Comment: Install the drivers from the manufacturer. If there are none, or they don't help, take it back to the store as defective.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. This question is essentially, 'what do I have to do differently to get this piece of hardware working properly in Windows 7'. Although OP notes a specific game, my guess is that it is a driver issue or some sort of Windows config. In my opinion, this is a reasonable question for SU.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton - This could either be a case of a driver problem which would then be solved by installing the driver or a gamepad support problem with FIFA 13.  In either case the current question does not have enough information to answer the question.

Comment: @TheCompWiz It would be useful for other people with this same device.

Comment: @KevinPanko This is a simple case of a user not reading the manual that came with the device.  SuperUser is not the place to ask obvious questions that are answered in the manual, on the manufacturer's website, and by some common-sense.  In this example... all three would have resolved his issue.

Comment: @TheCompWiz This is not obviously an obvious problem but a problem that has occured to several users without Xbox or Logitech gamepads. I think I have read all the instruction manuals too like other users who have the same problem. But if I am missing some context without which I cannot help, then I am most obviously willing to provide the information.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 drivers for this device are available from the manufacturer at [their website.](http://www.enter-multimedia.com/support.html)

Install them if you have not already.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to download the software known as Xpadder. It will help to run the all games which even do not support the gamepad. I also have the Enter E-GPV gamepad. Do some research on xpadder and it will surely help you. You can also check out this [Video Tutorial about Xpadder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1o5fcmuf1Sc)

Hope this helps. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on EA website. Just edit the registry and change USB Game-pad to something else

Read here - http://forum.ea.com/uk/posts/list/989111.page

Answer (score 0):

I know your problem 
That happened with me too.
There will be an analog button below start and select button. Just turn it on. 
You will get your RS and LS working..
And regarding problems in FIFA, once you see the reviews of Enter E-GPV on Flipkart
You will get your answer..
The review is given by JIAZ and in that he have described how to fix it.